# Add subcategories in Sharepoint blog categories

Tags: 2010, navigation, blog

How to add subcategories to categories in SharePoint 2010 blog? And can we display it in drop down list on homepage so that the user can navigate from there?

Answer (score 1):

Category is basically a choice field added to "Posts" list. You can use tree / hierarchy by adding taxonomy metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But I want to have a drop-down menu on the home page of the blog showing all categories.

Comment: Either you have to customize the menu to achieve your needs, or manually add menu from Navigation (max. is 2 level).